# WPF Canvas not rendering programmatically added children on XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I have developed a WPF application in .NET 4.0 that makes use of several Canvas UI elements. Everything works fine on my development machine that runs Windows 8.

I ran into problem when I tested that app in a virtual machine running Windows XP. Canvas renders elements added in XAML, but fails to render elements created in code.

Program was tested on Windows 8, Windows 7(VM) and Windows XP SP3(VM). Everything works fine except for the rendering of elements created in codebehind under XP. I have tested and elements are created, and properly added as children.

I have tried with manually setting Z index, calling UpdateLayout and InvalidateVisual, but to no avail.

Thanks for any help in advance.

UPDATE:
XAML

```
<Canvas Name="frontPresenter" Background="White"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
<Canvas Name="frontPlaceholderPresenter"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
               ElementName=frontPresenter}"
        Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
               ElementName=frontPresenter}"/>
```

C#

```
foreach (Models.BadgePosition position in currentItem.BadgesLayouts[layoutItem].BadgesPositions)
{
    double size = currentItem.FrontImage.Width * (position.Badge.BadgeImage == LanguageAssets.Controls.BadgePlaceholder ? 0.1d : 0.15d) * scale;
    Image img = new Image
    {
        Source = position.Badge.BadgeImage,
        Width = size,
        Height = size
    };
    img.DataContext = position;
    Canvas.SetTop(img, currentItem.FrontImage.Height * position.Y * scale);
    Canvas.SetLeft(img, currentItem.FrontImage.Width * position.X * scale);
    if (canvas == frontPresenter)
    {
        if (position.Badge.BadgeImage == LanguageAssets.Controls.BadgePlaceholder)
            frontPlaceholderPresenter.Children.Add(img);
        else
            canvas.Children.Add(img);
    }
    else
        canvas.Children.Add(img);
```

In essence, I want to print the final canvas, but not the placeholders. That is why I create placeholder images on the canvas in front and replace the images with the image user chooses on the same place but on the canvas meant for printing. This code does the job on Windows 8 and Windows 7 but bugs out on XP.

Note: Similar code

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(img);
new Window { Content = canvas }.Show();
```

will draw as expected on Windows 8 and 7, but will not render `img` object on XP.

Comment: Number 1 you should NOT be creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's a crappy practice, originated in dinosaur technologies' incapabilities to properly deal with data thru databinding. Number 2 post the relevant XAML and code.

Comment: Updated. I am just learning best practices of WPF and getting my sea legs. It came to mind to use what you suggested only after most of the program was completed and tested. I am reluctant to change it now unless it is 100% necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem solved. The answer was quite simple - corrupted installation of either .NET or SP3(My bet is on .NET). Same program was tested on two different VMs and worked perfectly.